# Does Cassandra CQL provide a command to generate an execution plan?

Tags: cassandra

In Oracle and other DBs you can generate an execution plan for SQL.

Is this possible for Cassandra?

I want to determine if it is possible to measure the relative complexity of several CQL statements to retrieve query data.

A Google search did not indicate that this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable tracing of the CQL queries, and see how it's executed. In CQLSH it's done with command `TRACING ON;`, after you finish set `TRACING OFF;`.

[This blog post](https://academy.datastax.com/support-blog/dude-where%E2%80%99s-my-data) provides more detailed description of it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot have only the explain plan without running the query, like in Oracle.
You have to trace your query, which is not quite the same.